# Specify theta.ml parameters within glmer.nb

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, convergence, mass

I am trying to fit a mixed-effect negative binomial model with `glmer.nb()` from package `lme4`.

```
m1 <- glmer.nb(NumberEvents ~ offset(log(days)) + x + (1|ID), data=dfr, nAGQ = 20)
```

I get the following warning:

> Warning message:
> In theta.ml(Y, mu, weights = object@resp$weights, limit = limit,  :
> iteration limit reached

I suppose I should increase the limit in the number of iterations of `theta.ml`.

```
theta.ml(limit = 1000)
```

How to do it? How can I call `theta.ml()` within `glmer.nb()`?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you can set the limit  inside `glmer.nb` as `initCtrl=list(limit=1000))`

Comment: Hi @AlvaroMartinez, I am facing the same error message, so I added in `initCtrl=list(limit=1000)` in `glmer.nb` as you suggested. But R shows the error message `unused argument (initCtrl = list(limit = 1000))`. I am wondering if you know how to solve it?

Comment: @karyn-h Try `optCtrl=list(limit=1e5)`.

Answer (score 4):

Although this is very old, I'll answer it for the record.

Once you hit the iteration limit, it is almost certainly the case that your data are equi- or underdispersed (i.e. variance <= mean). `glmer.nb` is trying to fit a negative binomial model, which becomes equi-dispersed (variance = mean) as the shape parameter goes to infinity.  If you look at the estimated shape parameter, you will typically find it is very large.

The appropriate solution is usually to revert to a Poisson model.